# How to get all classes from html to array using PHP

Tags: php, regex

Some things seems simple, yet this one has been killing me since yesterday.

I have a css file style.css so far I have been able to parse all the contents inside an array. All good there.

What I cant seem to figure out is how to get all the classes from a html file so i can compare it to my css array.

Example my code looks like this

```
      <div id="idtest" class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="flex-test1">
                 <div class="flex-test2">
                 </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

I have been trying to use the preg_match but i can only get this class="test" also it does not seem to pull all the ones I have in the file it only pulls the first one.

```
        preg_match('/class=".*?"/i', $value, $match);
        print_r($match);
```

```
(
 [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => idtest

        )
    [class] => Array
        (
            [0] => flex-center
            [1] => position-ref
            [2] => full-height
            [3] => flex-test1
            [4] => flex-test2

        )
)
```

Comment: Your want `preg_match_all` https://3v4l.org/lFdff

Comment: Another way, prob better is to use  xpath, then later without too much change or regex can only pick from divs etc https://3v4l.org/AhXjN

Comment: you are awesome. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your designed expression is fine, we might want to add a capturing group and the problem is likely solved:

```
$re = '/class="\s*(.*?)\s*"/s';
$str = '      <div id="idtest" class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="flex-test1">
                 <div class="flex-test2">
                 </div>
            </div>
      </div>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uWVoJj/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

Comment: Awesome thank you . I added the id="\s*(.*?)\s*"|class="\s*(.*?)\s*" and it pulled everything as needed.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try with jQuery.each() [here]https://api.jquery.com/each/ 
it will iterate DOMs elements an you can get the class.. (i dont have 50 reputation to put this as a comment so ..)

Comment: thank you, sadly i was looking for to get this done in php.